# Conditional formatting rules split and repeated

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have the problem that Excel 2010 splits the rules when copying and pasting a complete row with Conditional Formatting. Example:

1. Create a simple conditional rule like `=A1 <> ""` (if true, color the cell red) and assign the rule to the whole column A `$A:$A`.
2. Select the complete row 10, copy and paste it as row 11 in the same sheet.
   ==> Excel splits the rule into two rules:
   `=A1 <> ""` Applies to `$A$1:$A$10;$A$12:$A$1048576` and
   `=A1 <> ""` Applies to `$A$11`.

If the row is selected then the new row is inserted, without copying the current one, the rule is not split into two (still applied to `$A:$A`), the new row has the conditional formatting too.

I'm bound to insert new rows by copying/pasting an existing one because some of the cells contain formulas which must be copied too. So that is the easiest way to insert a new row.

Imagine 100 rows are inserted that way, then Excel will create 100 rules for the same rule. Thus the conditional formatting list is getting very unclear. A change to the formatting rule would be impossible.

How can I tell Excel that it should not split the rules when copying and pasting an existing row? Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 1):

When pasting choose Paste Special and check `All merging conditional formats`. Some details [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-paste-conditional-formatting-excel-54266.html).